# Not getting the same output as the tutorial

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am trying the Machine Learning tutorial on [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/dansbecker/your-first-machine-learning-model)

When they do it, they get the output as: [Kaggle outupt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nQRf.png)

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 5000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
# Read file from source
data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\harsh\Documents\My Dream\Desktop\Machine Learning\melb_data.csv", skiprows=0)

data = data.dropna(axis=0)

# Column that you want to predict = y
y = data.Price

# Columns that are inputted into the model to make predictions (dependants)
data_features = ['Rooms', 'Bathroom', 'Landsize', 'Lattitude', 'Longtitude']

X = data[data_features]

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor

# Define model. Specify a number for random_state to ensure same results each run
data_model = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=1)

# Fit model
data_model.fit(X, y)
```

My output is just

```
 Process finished with exit code 0
```

Whenever I want any output in the Run area, I have to put the function in `print()`

My question predominantly is:

1. How do I get the output as the Kaggle output in my PyCharm? Have I configured the IDE correctly?
2. Why do I need to put the `print()` function to display results every time? Do I need to do this svery time?
3. With print(), I get the output as:

   `DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=1)`

   What am I missing?

I am using PyCharm 2019.2.6 and Python 3.7 configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sklearn is not printing out the model parameters. You can print the `DecisionTreeRegressor` parameters with `print(data_model.get_params())`

Comment: Is there a way to get the output without the print function?

Comment: @Harshad It may be related to the version of sklearn, when I ran the example code in Jupyter I didn't have any output.